# Laravel : How get count from two table?

Tags: laravel

I have two table.

the first table:

```
- name_id
- name
```

the second table:

```
- counter_id
- name_id
- counter
```

and I made a button count (1) with a click . mean if I click to sum it inserts '1' in counter DB 
and finally, I want the result as

```
peter 4
sam 3
```

my code is

```
$data = DB::table('name')
       ->join('counters', 'counters.name_id', '=', 'name.name_id')
       ->select('name.name', 'counters.name_id') 
       ->get();

         return $data;
```

and result now

```
[
    {
        "name": "peter ",
        "name_id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "peter ",
        "name_id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "peter ",
        "name_id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "sam",
        "name_id": 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved in this way

````
        ->join('counters', 'counters.name_id', '=', 'name.name_id')
        ->select('name.name', DB::raw('Count(counters.name_id)'))
        ->groupBy('name.name')
        ->get();      
       ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this by using `collection` on laravel.

```
$data = [
    [
        "name" => "peter ",
        "name_id" => 1
    ],
    [
        "name" => "peter ",
        "name_id" => 1
    ],
    [
        "name" => "peter ",
        "name_id" => 1
    ],
    [
        "name" => "sam",
        "name_id" => 2
    ]
];

collect($data)->groupBy('name_id')->map(function($items) {
  return [
     'name' => $items[0]['name'],
     'total' => count($items)
  ];
})
```